# Selenium: Cannot access these radio buttons...Anyone willing to try?

Tags: selenium, iframe

Trying to access these Radio Toggle Buttons using Selenium:

http://codepen.io/JiveDig/pen/jbdJXR

Here is the code that I've tried so far

```
try {
    WebElement yesRadioButton = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 5)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#switch_left")));
    String isChecked = yesRadioButton.getAttribute("checked");
    assertTrue("Yes Button was not Checked", isChecked.equalsIgnoreCase("true"));
} catch (java.util.NoSuchElementException | TimeoutException e) {
    try {
        WebElement yesRadioButton = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 5)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"switch_left\"]")));
        String isChecked = yesRadioButton.getAttribute("checked");
        assertTrue("Yes Button was not Checked", isChecked.equalsIgnoreCase("true"));
    } catch (java.util.NoSuchElementException | TimeoutException e1) {
        WebElement yesRadioButton = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 5)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("switch_left")));
        String isChecked = yesRadioButton.getAttribute("checked");
        assertTrue("Yes Button was not Checked", isChecked.equalsIgnoreCase("true"));
    }
}
```

Comment: They are in an iframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
WebElement frame = 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='CodePen']"));
driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
WebElement yesRadioButton = (new WebDriverWait(driver,5)).until(
    ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
    By.xpath("//input[@id='switch_left']")));
```